# How to get xml attributes with php?

Tags: php, xml

I have api link.When I call this link,that link will be output xml data.

out put is

```
<note>
<something a="this is a" b="this is b" c="this is c">
<something a="this is a1" b="this is b1" c="this is c1">
<something a="this is a2" b="this is b2" c="this is c2">
<something a="this is a3" b="this is b3" c="this is c3">
</note>
```

I want to get something's attribute,How I can write with php.
I am beginner for php.Thank advanced my friend.

I want to write as following shown as.
I know this php code is something wrong,How to write correctly.

```
foreach($xml->something[0]->attributes() as $a => $b)
  {
  echo $a,'="',$b,"\"</br>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Let me know if it works for you...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach($xml->foo[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"</br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank my friend for you answers.What is $xml and $string, what different Please?

Comment: $string is you xml string, you can pass xml file also.

Comment: I see, Thank you for you contribute. I will try it

Comment: hello brother,I got this error message  Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement